# Yii: TbEditableColumn how to pass $data->id

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii

I am trying to use the `TbEditableColumn` and the type `select` to have a pulldown menu.
The pulldown menu I need is filled by a function that I call.
That is working for basic cases. But for a another column, the pulldown values are dependent from the row in which it is (`grid-view`).
So for example the function I want to call to fill the pulldown and pass the id of the current data is:

```
$model->getPulldownValues($data->id)
```

But that throws an error that the variable `$data` is not defined. The funny part is that outside the editable array, I can use $data as expected.
See example below:

Any ideas?

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
     'type' => 'striped bordered',
     'id'=>'order-image-grid',
     'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
     'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
     'template' => "{items}\n{extendedSummary}",
     'rowCssClassExpression'=>'"FMDBGridColumn".$data->order_error',
     'columns'=>array(
        array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
                'name' => 'streets',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150'),
                'value' => 'CHtml::value($data, "street")',
                'editable' => array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'source' => CHtml::listData($model->availableStreets($data->id), 'id', 'street'), 
                    'url' => $this->createUrl('cities/editable'),
                    'placement' => 'right',
                )
            ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: can you show full code please :D

Comment: Hi tinyByte, I have just added the total grid code, but removed other columns as it is a huge grid...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change method "availableStreets" into getter, e.g.:

```
public function getAvailableStreets()
{
    // we don't need to send id as parameter of method, 
    // we can get it directly from model
    // e.g.: $id = $this->id;
    // 
    // put your code here
}
```

then, in widget, use property

```
$model->availableStreets
```

instead of method

```
$model->availableStreets($id)
```

Also you can put 
CHtml::listData() into your getter and use

```
'source' => 'availableStreets',
```

instead of

```
'source' => CHtml::listData($model->availableStreets($data->id), 'id', 'street'),
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to consider that **$data** in `'value' => 'CHtml::value($data, "street")',` is referring to a model object which `$model->search()` is providing, but `$data` outside of the grid is different(You haven't shared what that is).

Comment: I need the exact same $data. In other words: I need to pass the id of the current row into `$model->availableStreets(ID OF RECORD OF CURRENT ROW)`. As far as I understand the grid, $data->id is the record-id of the current row. That is why I try to just put $data->id into the call...